# What are the requirements to bribe a guard in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've completed the Thieves Guild questline, and when a guard attempts an arrest there is a dialogue option that says, paraphrased, "I'm with the guild. Will this clear my bounty? (X gold)"

Then the guard says he can take care of it, but after that my only speech option is "Too rich for my blood". There's no actual dialogue choice to give up the gold.

Comment: Do you have that amount of gold?

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting 'Too rich for my blood' you must not have the amount of gold required to handle the bribe.

> 'Guards can be bribed to remove bounties even if you have a low Speech
>   skill and no bribe perk.'

[Thieves Guild Perks](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_%28faction%29#Advantages)

Some people on the uesp have mentioned bugs with having the correct money but still unable to bribe - if so, either set your crime gold to 0 or go to jail (saving first) it isn't hard to get your stuff back, especially if you have the Thieves Guild Perks. [Similar bug](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:To_Kill_an_Empire#Can.27t_pay_fine) [Set Crime Gold](http://skyrimforums.org/sf/threads/factions-ids-and-setcrimegold-command.1972/)